# Placing files manually in external storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I am new to Android. My question is: Can we put files on external storage folder (not hard coding but placing them manually) and make the app read them. 
Suppose  a folder like `myfiles/sdcard0/android/data/com.tmm.example/filestorage`
Now I want to place a file in that folder on my phone. Can I do that? I don't find any "add file" option there...the only thing I find is "create folder"...

If we can, how to do that?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create files using the stock file browser on Android, for this you need a new app. The best one on the Google Market (free) is this app: [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en_GB)

1. Download and open the app
2. Navigate to your external storage folder
3. Click the "New" button on the bottom left
4. Then in the new option window, choose "File"
5. That's it

Hope that helps.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear..I want to place the file in external storage folder manually..not from code..can we do that?

Comment: Lol yes I just realised too, I'm currently editing my answer. Please wait 5 mins

Comment: There you go. Please check the answer now.

Comment: I see. The normal stock file browser on android does not let you "create file", but if you download this app called ES File Explorer, it lets you create files. Maybe that is what you need?

Comment: ya..exactly wat I was looking for...So if we download the ES File explorer we can add files to external storage folder r8??

Comment: Exactly, just open the ES File Explorer, go to your external storage and click "New" at the bottom left, and it will display a window giving you option to create new "File" or "Folder". That's it!

Comment: No problem, I have put detailed instructions on the above answer now.

Comment: Anyway, this kind of questions are very risky. Someone could downvote it because it does not concerns to programming. See the related help page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask